# Basic Homogenous Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x^2y+x^3}{y^3+2x^3}$$

I have identified that the differential equation is homogeneous because $f(rx,ry)$ = $r^3f(x,y)$ . I then used the substitution $u = y/x$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = x\frac{du}{dx} + u$ reducing the equation to $$x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{2u^3} + \frac{1}{u^2}$$ I believe i have made a mistake somewhere in the middle of this and if not how would I go about solving this differential equation. (The only methods that have been presented in class are 1st order linear using mu substitution, separable, exact, homogeneous and Bernoulli).  If it helps my profesor wrote down a solution $y = \int \frac{v+1}{v^3+2}$dv (He did not have the dv but i believe he just forgot it so I added it)

Comment: Your second equation is also separable.

Comment: The substitution $u=y/x$ gives $x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2u+1}{u^3+2}-u$ so you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: If the substitution is correct (I haven't checked that) this equation is now separable

Comment: You certainly made an error: $f(rx,ry) = f(x,y)$, without the $r^3$ term.

Answer (score 0):

On substituting $u=\frac{y}{x}$ in the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x^2y+x^3}{y^3+2x^3}$$
we get 
$$x\frac{du}{dx} + u = \frac{2u+1}{u^3+2}$$
or $$x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2u+1-u^4-2u}{u^3+2}$$
or $$\frac{u^3+2}{1-u^4}du = \frac{dx}{x}$$
or $$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{-4u^3}{1-u^4}du + \frac{2}{(1-u^2)(1+u^2)}du= \frac{dx}{x}$$
or $$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{d(1-u^4)}{(1-u^4)} + \frac{(1-u^2)+(1+u^2)}{(1-u^2)(1+u^2)}du= \frac{dx}{x}$$
or $$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{d(1-u^4)}{(1-u^4)} + \frac{du}{1+u^2} + \frac{du}{1-u^2}= \frac{dx}{x}$$

Integrating both sides, we get that
$$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot \ln|1-u^4| + \arctan u + \frac{1}{2}\ln|\frac{1+u}{1-u}|=\ln |x| + c$$

Hope this helps.